# Using Intellij IDEA 14 to remote debug an Application on a Tomcat Server while using JRebel

Tags: java, tomcat7, remote-debugging, jrebel, intellij-14

I can do this in eclipse, but when I try to do it in Intellij the remote debugger bogs down and the Application throws an IllegalThreadStateException.

Is there a setting that I need to configure in Intellij, or a procedure I need to do to get this to work properly?

Comment: There are no special configurations. Just put the break points in the source you want and start remote debuging in the same port you use

Answer (score 1):

Could you mail the JRebel Support team these 2 documents? (support@zeroturnaround.com)

1. The full stack trace of the `IllegalThreadStateException`
2. A TRACE-level `jrebel-intellij.log`

Obviously first update your JRebel plugin to the very latest version (6.1.2 on day of writing) as the last couple of minor releases specifically fixed debugger issues, if this is not yet the case.

Then in IntelliJ open up: `Preferences -> JRebel -> Advanced -> JRebel IDE plugin log level = Trace`. Reproduce the issue and find the file here: `$HOME/.jrebel/jrebel-intellij.log`